# Can anyone explain why the combinatorical identity $\sum_{t=2}^{l_1} \binom{n-t}{k-2} = \binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-l_1}{k-1}$ is true?

Tags: combinatorics

When I type $\sum_{t=2}^{l_1} \frac{(n-t)!}{(n-t-k+2)!}$ into Wolfram alpha, I get an answer that simplifies to $\binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-l_1}{k-1}$.

Can anyone explain why this simplifies so nicely? Is there a combinatorial identity or something such?

I've only gotten as far as recognizing that the initial sum can be written as $\sum_{t=2}^{l_1} \binom{n-t}{k-2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use that
$$
\binom{n-t}{k-2}=\binom{n-t+1}{k-2+1}-\binom{n-t}{k-2+1}
$$and see that your sum telescopes.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
We'll use the identity
$\ds{\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{a} \over z^{b + 1}}
     \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} = {a \choose b}}$.

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{t = 2}^{\ell_{1}}{n-t \choose k-2}} & =
\sum_{t = 2}^{\ell_{1}}
\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - t} \over z^{k - 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{1 \over z^{k - 1}}
\sum_{t = 2}^{\ell_{1}}\pars{1 + z}^{n - t}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{1 \over z^{k - 1}}\,\pars{1 + z}^{n - 2}\,
{\pars{1 + z}^{-\pars{\ell_{1} - 1}} - 1 \over \pars{1 + z}^{-1} - 1}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm] & =
-\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z^{k}}\,
\bracks{{\pars{1 + z}^{-\pars{\ell_{1} - 1}} - 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm] & =
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z^{k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
-
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - \ell_{1}} \over z^{k}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic} =
\color{#f00}{{n - 1 \choose k - 1} - {n - \ell_{1} \choose k - 1}}
\end{align}